# How to transform the table to match the column name in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: The expected behaviour]

I want to transform the table to get the value in highlight part, what should be the right formula for the cells?

Comment: Use a pivot table?

Comment: could you please tell me the detailed steps?

Answer (score 0):

Do some google search for `Pivot table` as @BigBen suggested. You can also use formulas. With `Excel365` you can use `XLOOKUP()`.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,($A$3:$A$16=F$2)*($B$3:$B$16=$E3),$C$3:$C$16,"")
```

You can try `SUMPRODUCT()` for other Excel version .

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$3:$C$16)*($A$3:$A$16=F$2)*($B$3:$B$16=$E3))
```

`INDEX/MATCH` will also work. Here is example

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$16,MATCH(F$2&$E3,$A$3:$A$16&$B$3:$B$16,0)),"")
```

You may need to array `CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER` entry this formula for `Non365` version of excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Pivot Table

A pivot table would be the best way to summarize this data - all you would need to do is follow these steps.

1. Select the data.
2. Go to Insert>Pivot Table...
3. Drag the Date field to the column section.
4. Drag the Name field to the row section.
5. Drag the Number field to the Values section.

### Formulas

If you want to do it solely with formulas enter this in F2,

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A3:A16))
```

this in E3,

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(B3:B16))
```

and this in F3:J9.

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$16,$A$3:$A$16,F$2,$B$3:$B$16,$E3)
```

Change the range to enter the last formula based on the no of unique dates and no of unique names.